# How do I set a MySQL/ODBC connection in Excel from Delphi?

Tags: excel, delphi, ole, listobject

I want to create a new Excel workbook from Delphi, but before I open it from Delphi, I first want to set up an ODBC connection to an existing MySQL database, and set the query.
Then as it opens, it will extract the data straight away.

What I tried is first recording the macro in Excel, and seeing how it set up the connection in VBA.
I then attempted to replicate the VBA in Delphi.

This is what I have tried:

```
var
xls, wb : OLEVariant;
begin
  xls := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application'); {initialize an instance of Excel}
  wb := xls.Workbooks.Add; {create workbook}

  //xls.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:='ODBC;DSN=MySQL;', Destination:=Range('$A$1')).QueryTable; //this throws a missing operator or semicolon error
  xls.Worksheets[1].ListObjects.Add(); //add a listobject
  xls.WorkBooks[1].Worksheets[1].ListObjects.Item[1].QueryTable[1].CommandText := 'SELECT 1';
...
end;
```

On trying to set the CommandText though, I get an OLE error 800A03EC

This below is the VBA code.
I get it by recording the Macro from a new workbook.
On the very first line I have tried so many combinations on how to enter the connection string, eventually I figured out that I could add a ListObject (as in my Delphi code) without any errors, after which I then tried to set each parametr separately, but without success.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DSN=MySQL;", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = 0
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT 1")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MySQL"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What and where is the code that tells Excel that QueryTable1 refers to a table in your MySql database?  Your q needs a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That's my issue, I don't know what needs to come before, hence I just used a "SELECT 1" query to try testing it as that won't reference an existing table. I have spent yesterday and today searching for what needs to be included, with very little progress.Everything I find is VB code.

Comment: Please show the VBA code which you said it worked. Edit your question with that code.

Comment: Look at your Delphi code for `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add()`. Compare it to the VBA code `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DSN=MySQL;",         Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable`. You can't see the difference between the two?

Comment: @KenWhite:  Thank you for my laugh-out-loud of the day.  Maybe the OP hasn't realised that he needs to link the worksheet to the ODBC datasource using his DSN name for the MySql database.

Comment: @MartynA: It seems the OP didn't read the VBA code very well, and just grabbed a couple of lines almost at random. They clearly didn't see the ODBC information at all. :-)

Comment: I did actually try that. Doing  "xls.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:='ODBC;DSN=MySQL;', Destination:=Range('$A$1')).QueryTable;" instead of what I have, I gives the error of a missing operator or semicolon.

Comment: I suggest you edit the **exact** code you tried into your q - the "missing operator or semicolon" sounds more like a simple Delphi syntax error in your code than an error in the Excel code.

Comment: Added what I have tried in Delphi (commented out) above the line ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add()

Comment: @fpiette Sorry to reach out to you specifically, but you took the trouble to initially consider my question, do you see anything I might be doing wrong, or suggestion on how to fix it? I would really appreciate any further input please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which is almost a direct copy of VBA code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    ExcelApplication       : Variant;
    WorkBook               : Variant;
    ActiveSheet            : Variant;
    ListObject             : Variant;
    Range                  : Variant;
    QueryTable             : Variant;
begin
    ExcelApplication                    := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
    WorkBook                            := ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add;
    ActiveSheet                         := ExcelApplication.ActiveSheet;
    Range                               := ActiveSheet.Range['A1', 'A1'];
    ListObject                          := ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(
                                  0,                 // SourceType,
                                  'ODBC;DSN=MySQL;', // Source,
                                  TRUE,              // LinkSource,
                                  xlGuess,           //XlListObjectHasHeaders,
                                  Range);            // Destination
    QueryTable                          := ListObject.QueryTable;
    QueryTable.CommandType              := xlCmdSql;
    QueryTable.CommandText              := 'SELECT 1';
    QueryTable.RowNumbers               := FALSE;
    QueryTable.FillAdjacentFormulas     := FALSE;
    QueryTable.PreserveFormatting       := TRUE;
    QueryTable.RefreshOnFileOpen        := FALSE;
    QueryTable.BackgroundQuery          := TRUE;
    QueryTable.RefreshStyle             := xlInsertDeleteCells;
    QueryTable.SavePassword             := FALSE;
    QueryTable.SaveData                 := TRUE;
    QueryTable.AdjustColumnWidth        := TRUE;
    QueryTable.RefreshPeriod            := 0;
    QueryTable.PreserveColumnInfo       := TRUE;
    QueryTable.ListObject.DisplayName   := 'Table_Query_from_MySQL';
    QueryTable.Refresh(False);  // BackgroundQuery
end;
```

As you see, I have used intermediate variables for code readability. You could omit some of them.

Comment: I couldn't get the xlCmdSql, xlInserrtDeleteCells, and xlGuess to not throw errors, so I removed them.

Comment: ListObject                          := ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(
        SourceType                      := 0,
        Source                          := 'ODBC;DSN=MySQL;',
        Destination                     := Range);

Comment: @Shamusvw your said "I couldn't get the xlCmdSql, xlInserrtDeleteCells, and xlGuess to not throw errors, so I removed them.". What are the errors? Compile time? Run time?

Comment: It is a compile time error, Undeclared identifier" 'xlGuess'. Similar for any other identifier starting with xl, e.g. xlInsertDeleteCells But I just remove them and it gives me exactly what I want, i.e. opening up the Excel spreadsheet with the ODBC connection created and the query extracts data. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate you persevering with me to get it working.

Comment: xlGuess and other identifiers are defined in Excel2000.pas which comes with Delphi. Add Excel2000 to you uses clause, or use these const definitions: xlGuess = $00000000; xlCmdSql = $00000002; xlInsertDeleteCells = $00000001;

Comment: thank you for all your help. Adding Excel2000 sorted out the issues to now use e.g. xlGuess. Adding it meant I had to explicitly define other identifiers, but that was easy enough. For example FLOOR, I had to make it math.FLOOR. Again, thank you. I am now using what I have been taught here, and it works well.